# Error Code LNK2019 & LNK1120

Tags: c++

I create this file over and over and cant seem to see why I'm getting this error. I tried going to the line where the code is but the format seem correct I may just need another set of eyes .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void readString(char*, int);
void changeToUppercase(char*, int);
void displayStringInUppercase(char*, int);

int main()
{
    int arraySize;
    char* characterArray;

    cout << "Enter the size of dynamic array: ";
    cin >> arraySize;

    characterArray = new char[arraySize];

    readString(characterArray, arraySize);

    changeToUppercase(characterArray, arraySize);

    displayStringInUppercase(characterArray, arraySize);

    delete [] characterArray;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

void changeToUppercase(char* characterArray, int arraySize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        characterArray[i] = toupper(characterArray[i]);
}

void displayStringInUppercase(char* characterArray, int arraySize)
{
    cout << "\nThestring inupper case letters: ";

    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        characterArray[i] = toupper(characterArray[i]);
}
```

This is the error codes that keep popping up:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl readString(char *,int)" (?readString@@YAXPADH@Z) referenced in function _main

fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Near as I can tell, you declared and used, but never implemented the readString function.

Comment: @Niall I should just bookmark that sucker. Couldn't find it with the googz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a forward declaration: `void readString(char*, int);` but then never actually define this function.

Define your `readString` function later in your code like...

```
void readString(char* str, int a)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the readString function. You have a forward declaration that satisfies the compiler here

```
void readString(char*, int);
```

But no actual implementation of the function to satisfy the linker when it tries to put your program together. You need something along the lines of

```
void readString(char* characterArray, int arraySize)
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Hahaha our answers are practically identical

Comment: @bpgeck Not surprising. Only so many ways to solve this without knowing what's supposed to go inside readString.